# ASP.NET webform error with JQuery Mobile

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

Here is my effort for using JQuery mobile with asp.net webform. Below is the code I have used in the Default.aspx page. **It's a very simple code**

Below is the complete code of the aspx page.

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title> Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="foo">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Mobile Login</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">   
        <table width="100%">
           <tr width="100%">
             <td width="30%" align="right" valign="middle">
               <asp:Literal ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="User Name"></asp:Literal>
             </td>
             <td width="50%">
               &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="text" maxlength="20" id="UserName" style="width:50%;"  runat="server" />
             </td>
           </tr>
            <tr width="100%">
             <td width="50%"  align="right">
             <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Literal>
             </td>
             <td width="50%">
              &nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" maxlength="20" id="Password" style="width:50%;" runat="server" />
             </td>
           </tr>
            <tr width="100%">
             <td width="50%" align="right">

             </td>
             <td width="50%">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="30%">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login"
                         OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
                      </td>
                      <td width="30%">
                       <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel"  CssClass="ui-btn-active"
                         OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />
                      </td>
                      <td width="40%">

                      </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
             </td>
           </tr>
        </table>        
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>
          @ All right reserved.
        </h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now on the server side

```
  protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Home.aspx",true);

}
protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserName.Value = "";
    Password.Value = ""; 
}
```

but when I am clicking the login/cancel button nothing happen other than the Url is changed from

> http://localhost:2278/Mobile/Default.aspx

to

> http://localhost:2278/Mobile/Default.aspx#/Mobile/Default.aspx

What is wrong in my code? Can't I access Server side functions from ASP.NET server controls in JQuery Mobile? I am aware that it can be done better in MVC but that's not a option for me in this case.

Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because .net adds `type="submit"` to Button control by default. You need to set that to false and I would also set `CausesValidation` to false too, like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login"
OnClick="btnLogin_Click" CausesValidation="False" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

in all fairness however, I wouldn't have used a server-side event just to navigate away on button click. You can achieve that with much easier way:

```
<a href="Home.aspx" data-role="button">Login</a>
```

..that's, of course, assuming you don't have to do any other server-side operations before navigating away.

Comment: Thanks! it works. The reason I am using link <a> because I have to do some server side validation/authentication for the logged in user which needs to be checked from the database.

Comment: I am also not sure that using ASP.NET controls will be helpful for me or not.. I seriously doubt these controls on mobile devices. but I can not go beyond my client requirement. they don't want to use MVC.

Comment: that's OK, they all become html controls in the end of the day. Just make sure you view generated source to see what .net adds to its controls behind the scenes.